# Vector Bundle vs Geometric Vector Bundle vs Locally Free Sheaf in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have read some books on algebraic geometry. And the vector bundle, geometric vector bundle, or locally free sheaf (or invertible sheaf if it have rank 1) are used in each book. I know their definitions, and their relations in a sheaf of sections and symmetric algebra. However, it makes me very confusing because different books use any of vector bundles, geometric vector bundles, or locally free sheaf.

Is there a good way to understand it?

Comment: Shouldn't knowing their relations in terms of "sheaf of sections and symmetric algebra" tell you all you need to know? A geometric vector bundle is equivalent to a locally free sheaf via the sheaf of sections, and the relative spectrum of the symmetric algebra of a locally free sheaf gives an associated vector bundle (up to possibly a dualization, depending on your source). The moral is they're the same thing.

Comment: If it's all I need to know, I think it's better to think of it as something different. For example, can we define a very ample geometric vector bundle of rank 1?

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about. Good luck.

Comment: If a vector bundle and a geometric vector bundle are the same, we should be able to define a very ample geometric vector bundle of rank 1 just as a very ample line bundle. However, I have never seen a very ample geometric vector bundle of rank 1. Therefore, I think it is more natural to think of vector bundles and geometric vector bundles as different things.

Comment: I'm sorry if there is a book that defines a very ample geometric vector bundle of rank 1.

Comment: A geometric line bundle is very ample if the associated invertible sheaf is very ample. In the language of such things, I guess what you want is something like: a line bundle $\pi:L\to X$ is **very ample** if it has sections $s_i:X\to L$ (remember, these are literally morphisms of schemes such that $\pi\circ s_i=id_X$) with the property that the map $X \dashrightarrow \mathbb P^n$ given by $x\mapsto [s_0(x):s_1(x):\cdots:s_n(x)]$ (suitably interpreted on affine patches blah blah blah) is a morphism (this property in isolation makes it **basepoint free**), but more than that a closed embedding.